# Does Cloudflare allowed the Update DNS Record in API Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, cloudflare

I was trying update an IP DNS on Cloudflare using Python API. Everything looks good there were not any errors but a record did not change. When I checked:

```
parametrsToChange ={"zone_name": "mypage.com", "type": "A", "name": "xyz.mypage.com", "content": "1.2.3.4", "ttl": 1, "proxied": False}
credentials = {"X-Auth-Key": "XXXX", "X-Auth-Email": "name@name.com", "Content-Type": "application/json"
print(requests.put('https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/zone_identifier/dns_records/identifier', parametrsToChange, headres=credentials)
<Response [405]>
```

According to the [Cloudflare documentation](https://api.cloudflare.com/#getting-started-responses) it's "Method Not Allowed incorrect HTTP method provided" any solution to solve the problem?

Comment: Hope you have replaced `zone_identifier` & `record_identifier` with their valid values

Comment: Yes I have replaced it.

Comment: Also you have a typo `headres` where it should be `headers`